# Query for creating buffer around particular point using PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am working on a project for ambulance management using GIS. Using QGIS, PostgreSQL and PostGIS I am finding it difficult querying using St_dwithin as well as St_buffer.
My aim is to find any hospitals available to a victim within a particular radius.  I have the information of the victims locations in form of geometry.

Answer (score 2):

[PostGIS FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#id459661) answers that question. The two geography values that you give to ST_DWithin are the victim location that you have and the hospital location you should have in your database.

Answer (score 2):

The closest (in straight line) Hospital from the event can be found with a query like this:

```
Select 
      id, 
      st_distance(a.geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT($X $Y)', <SRID>)) as distance 
from
      data.hospital_db as a
ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1;
```

The query calculates for each hospital the [distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) between them and the [event](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_GeomFromText.html), and then it returns the `id` of the hospital and the `distance` between them in straight line .

Then it [orders](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) the hospital with an ascending order based on the `distance`. It returns only the [first](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) result.

Also be sure to check your projection, one degree is not equal to one kilometer!